# Designing dialog box in R

Tags: r, messagebox, dialog

How can we a design a dialog box in R?

In my mind I have something in which an alert message is displayed or where we can write a certain value and then clicking a button it performs some computation... is that possible within the R workspace?

Comment: The `tcltk` package would be a place to start.

Comment: As an alternative you might want to try out [gWidgets](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets/index.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
library("tcltk")
button <- tkmessageBox(title='Message',message='Error x!',type='ok')
button <- tclvalue(button)
if(button == 'ok'){
  #do something
}
```

Comment: Where to find the pdf guide for this package?

Answer (score 6):

winDialog also works:

```
library(utils)
answer<-winDialog("yesno", "was the suggestion useful?")
if (answer=='YES') {print('good!')} else {print('sorry')}
```

Just try to copy the full code and paste it into your R console: a dialog box will come out and a final output ('good!' or 'sorry') will appear depending on the answer you click.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

- `utils`: `select.list` if you are choosing from pre-set alternatives. `edit` is more general, but less polished.
- `gWidgets`: Interfaces with either `tcltk` or `RGtk2` to produce dialogues. `gmessage` and `ginput` are probably what you are looking for.